# Website prefix in all urls with Webpack and React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webpack, routes, react-router-v4

I am using Nginx and I am going to host two apps on a single domain but two different prefixes (for example "http://www.example.com/bookstore" and "http://www.example.com/library"). Nginx is doing the proxy and does a good job with routing to the host for my index.html with my React app. The problem is that webpack builds the website without knowledge about that proxy, so when my website is "http://www.example.com/library", the index.html has src for the js file described as "static/js/main.js" so the effect is 404 - file not found.

The second part of the problem is that Router 4 doesn't know how to route the prefix. Can I globally declare a prefix for the app in package.json? Even if I set up ma app properly, the routings are going to go crazy with 404's because (again) route app for Router 4 is "http://www.example.com/" not "http://www.example.com/library".